# Style tnode.children with React Native Render HTML custom rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-render-html

I want to add a `strike-through` decoration to the `#text`-node-like children of a particular item we render using [custom rendering](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/docs/guides/custom-renderers).

But I'm not aware of any way to actually target the child `#text`-like-node and apply styles to it.

For example, we could wrap the `TChildrenRenderer` like below, but those styles will not be inherited by the `Text` component that `TChildrenRenderer` renders. So this works for some styles, like `lineDecorationType: 'line-through'`, but not for things like `color`.

```js
<Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>
    <TChildrenRenderer tchildren={tnode.children} />
</Text>
```

Is there any approach that would allow us to set `color` on the inner rendered text?

---

**Edit**: The method has to allow for conditional styling, so a top-level prop like `defaultTextProps` is out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add `textProps` but only on the parent `TDefaultRenderer`. May be good enough in your use case (?).

```
<TDefaultRenderer textProps={{ style: { color: 'red' }}}
```

Or possibly, on `<RenderHtml>` add `defaultTextProps={{ style: { color: 'red' }}}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It seems sensible, but it doesn't appear to have any effect. I also tried `viewProps` and `nativeProps`, but nothing!

Comment: Hmm, and the `TDefaultRenderer ` was wrapping as direct parent of `TChildrenRenderer `?

Comment: have edited with alternative

Comment: `TDefaultRenderer` is not wrapping `TChildrenRenderer` directly (otherwise I don't see the  point of custom renderers.) Unfortunately `defaultTextProps` isn't an option because we need to apply these styles to an element conditionally. I see I forgot to mention that, so I've edited my question. Sorry!

Comment: Ah I see. I think you are looking for https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/api/renderhtmlprops#idsstyles ?

Comment: That _might_ work, but then we'd have to pre-process our HTML - unless the `id` for an element can be set from inside of `domVisitors`? Not terribly elegant if it does work - but if it does work, I'll let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249125/discussion-between-slbox-and-adsy).

Comment: It can be done via assigning the `class` attribute to the element inside of `domVisitors`, and then styling using `classesStyles`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `renderChild` prop from [`TChildrenRendererProps`](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/api/tchildrenrendererprops). Something like:

```js
const renderRedChild = ({ childElement }) => React.cloneElement(childElement, {...childElement.props, style: [childElement.props.style, { color: "red" }]})
//...
<TChildrenRenderer tchildren={tnode.children} renderChild={renderRedChild} />
```